# ASP.net MVC 4 Routing and optional parameters unexpected result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Here is my route, the only required param is the controller

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "countryoptional/controller",
            "{country}/{controller}/{pagelabel}/{page}",
            new { action = "index", country = UrlParameter.Optional,  pagelabel = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new
            {
                pays = @"$|^(france|belgium)$",
                controller = @"^(car|boat)$",
                pagelabel = @"^$|page",
                page = @"^$|\d{1,6}"
            }
        );
```

I'm expecting the following URLS to work with :

/car/

/car/page/2

/france/car

/france/car/page/2

It kind of works :

```
Url.Action("index", "car", new { country= "france", pagelabel = "page", page = 2} )
```

Will produce : ***/france/car/page/2***

BUT

If I want an url without a country the view action respond but a constructor like

```
Url.Action("index", "car", new { pagelabel = "page", page = 2} )
```

will produces this link : ***//car/page/2***

I get this double slash "//car" so it breaks the link of course.

I suspect the fact it does not like the possibility of the {country} parameter preceding controller optional in the {country}/{controller}/... url definition
I don't want to complicate my route config and having another route declaration
There must be a way, what I'm I doing wrong ?

Comment: In your optional parameters, you have pays instead of country. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm not too good with regex, but I believe you are adding a constraint saying to make sure that the country is either france or belgium. So when you don't provide it, it doesn't set the value of the country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optional parameters must follow any required parameters. There's no way around this that I know of. The same limitation applies everywhere else (your method definitions, etc.).

Just repeat the route and have one with a required country and one without any country. MVC will work out which one to use.

Comment: "Optional parameters must follow any required parameters." I didn't know about that rule, I guess that answer the question, thanks